# Creating array from AnyObject in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array of AnyObject type like this: [[String : AnyObject]]

> animalList = [["name": ABC, "color":red], ["name": DEF, "color":
>   green], ["name": GHI, "color": blue ]]

The model class is like this:

```
class ModelAnimal {

    var name: String
    var color: String

    init(name: String, color: String){
        self.name = name
        self.color = color 
    }
}
```

How can I put them in an array of ModelAnimal type:

```
var myList = Array<ModelAnimal>()

    for var i = 0; i < animalList.count; i++ {

     myList.

    }
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile as-is.  Are the values `ABC` and the colors like `red` Strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `map` to create a new array of type `[ModelAnimal]`:

```
let animalList: [[String: AnyObject]] = [["name": "ABC", "color":"red"], ["name": "DEF", "color": "green"], ["name": "GHI", "color": "blue"]]

class ModelAnimal {

    var name: String
    var color: String

    init(name: String, color: String){
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
    }
}

let myList = animalList.map { ModelAnimal(name: $0["name"] as? String ?? "", color: $0["color"] as? String ?? "") }
```

This also makes use of *conditional cast* `as? String` along with the *nil coalescing operator* `??` to safely extract the values from the array of dictionaries and pass them to the constructor for `ModelAnimal`.

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Struct

First suggestion, use a `Struct` instead of a `Class` the model.

Why a Struct?

1. A Struct does allow you to define a `failable init` that can return fail without initialising all the stored properties.
2. A Struct is saved into the Stack Memory of your device that is much faster then the heap.
3. Finally if the `name` and `color` field are not going to change you should really declare them as `let`. This way you Struct is going to be totally immutable (that is good for several reasons).

### 2. Failable initializer

Add a `failable inititializer` to your model that receives optional params

```
struct ModelAnimal {

    let name: String // you can change this back to var if needed
    let color: String  // you can change this back to var if needed

    init(name: String, color: String){
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
    }

    init?(name: String?, color: String?) {
        guard let name = name, color = color else { return nil }
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
    }
}
```

### 3. flatMap

Now you can use the powerful `flapMap` function

```
let animals = animalList.flatMap { ModelAnimal(name: $0["name"], color: $0["color"]) }
```

Why flatMap?

1. The beauty of `flatMap` is that it does returns only **non nil values**.
   Infact  `animalList` contains unstructured data and you have no guarantee (at least at compile time) that each element has a `name` and a `color` key. This way if bad data is contained into `animalList` it is simply discarded.
2. Another advantage of `flatMap` is that it does return an `array` of `ModelAnimal`, not `ModelAnimal?`.

Comment: Nice!  You are going to need a cast to deal with the fact that the values in the dictionary are `AnyObject`.

Comment: I didn't think you could have a failable initializer with the same signature as a non-failable one.

Comment: @MikeAtNobel: actually the 2 initialisers don't have the same signature. `String` and `String?` are different types.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess that is enough information for the compiler to decide which initializer to use. +1

Answer (score 0):

First `initialize` your ModelAnimal objects, then add them to an array:

```
let animalOne = ModelAnimal(name: "ABC", color: "red")
let animalTwo = ModelAnimal(name: "DEF", color: "green")
let animalThree = ModelAnimal(name: "GHI", color: "blue")

let myList: Array<ModelAnimal> = [animalOne, animalTwo, animalThree]
```

You could also do this in-line:

```
let myList: Array<ModelAnimal> = [ModelAnimal(name: "ABC", color: "red"), ModelAnimal(name: "DEF", color: "green"), ModelAnimal(name: "GHI", color: "blue")]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code just iterates over `animalList` and adds new items to `myList`:

```
var myList = Array<ModelAnimal>()

for var i = 0; i < animalList.count; i++ {
    myList.append(ModelAnimal(name: animalList[i]["name"]!, color: animalList[i]["color"]!))
}
```

It works, however calling `append` every time isn't good for performance. Better way to achieve this is to create array with needed length:

```
for var i = 0; i < animalList.count; i++ {
    myList[i] = ModelAnimal(name: animalList[i]["name"]!, color: animalList[i]["color"]!)
}
```